# Include default query param values in requestURI in Jersey if they are omitted

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

Is there a way to have query parameter "x" be included in the URL with the default value if it is omitted, because currently what I need to do is the following below and I have to do that for each parameter with a default value; is there a better way to do this? I am using Jersey version 1.12

```
    public Response getResponse(@DefaultValue("test") @QueryParam("x") String x)
                UriBuilder uriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromUri(uriInfo.getRequestUri());
                uriBuilder = uriBuilder.replaceQueryParam(x);
                QueryContext.setUrl(uriBuilder.build().toString());
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a standard Jersey way to do this but you could intercept the method with AOP and do something like:

```java
public class UpdateQueryParamInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation method) throws Throwable {
    UriBuilder builder = null;
    for (Object arg: method.getArguments()) {
      if (arg instanceof UriInfo) {
        UriInfo info = (UriInfo)arg;
        builder = UriBuilder.fromUri(info.getRequestUri());
      }
    }

    Annotation[][] annotations = method.getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();
    for (int i = 0; i < method.getArguments().length; i++) {
      if (annotations[i].length > 0) {
        DefaultValue def = null;
        QueryParam param = null;

        for (Annotation annotation: annotations[i]) {
          if (annotation instanceof DefaultValue) {
            def = (DefaultValue)annotation;
          } else if (annotation instanceof QueryParam) {
            param = (QueryParam)annotation;
          }
        }
        if ((null != def) && (null != param)) {
          builder = builder.replaceQueryParam(param.value(), method.getArguments()[i]);
        }
      }
    }

    //Do something with builder.build().toString()); 

    return method.proceed();
  }

}
```

I wasn't sure what `QueryContext` class was in your code - but you could find that in the method also and perform the `setUrl` method in the interceptor...